# Boto3 S3 client methods throw NoSuchBucket even it has

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I am trying to select one existing bucket then upload file into the bucket using Boto3.
But all methods related with buckets aren't working correctly for me.

**The problems I'm confronting are like this:**

- When I list up the buckets using `boto3.Session.client('s3').list_buckets()` method, it results an empty list of Buckets.
- When I select a specific bucket using `boto3.Session.resource('s3').Bucket('existing_bucket_name')` then run `upload_fileobj()` method, it throws `NoSuchBucket` exception(which is very ridiculous the Bucket object's attribute `name` correctly returns the bucket's name though).

**What I've tried so far:**

1. used `Session` instance with keyword arguments indicating account and region configuration. I had some issues with Boto3 config setup and finally gave up using config file then directly gave the instance config arguments.
2. used `resource` instead of `client`. `client` method didn't work correctly, so I used `resource` but it also didn't go well.

**here is my code:**

1. Implemented client class

```py
class S3Client:

    def __init__(self):
        region = 'ap-northeast-2'
        self.session = boto3.Session(
            aws_access_key_id=os.environ['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
            aws_secret_access_key=os.environ['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'],
            region_name=region
        )
        self.client = self.session.client(service_name='s3', region_name=region,
                                          aws_access_key_id=os.environ['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
                                          aws_secret_access_key=os.environ['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'])
        self.resource = self.session.resource('s3')
        self.bucket = self.resource.Bucket(settings.AWS_S3['BUCKET_NAME'])

    @staticmethod
    def open_test_file_as_byte():
        file_name = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'test_file.pdf')

        data = open(file_name, 'rb')
        return data

    def upload_file(self, file_name):
        with self.open_test_file_as_byte() as file_byte_stream:
            return self.bucket.upload_fileobj(
                file_byte_stream,
                'reports/' + file_name,
                ExtraArgs={'ACL': 'public-read-write'}
        )

    # this method worked once with message saying that creation successfully completed, but I cannot find anything in my S3
    def create_bucket(self):
        return self.client.create_bucket(
            ACL='public-read-write',
            Bucket='public-reports'
            # CreateBucketConfiguration={
            #     'LocationConstraint': 'ap-northeast-2'
            # }
        )
```

2. Codes that invoke the client's method

```py
@mock_s3
class S3ClientTestCases(unittest.TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls) -> None:
        cls.s3_client = S3Client()

    def test_create_bucket(self):
        logger.debug(self.s3_client.create_bucket())
        logger.debug(self.s3_client.client.list_buckets())

    def test_upload_file(self):
        logger.debug(self.s3_client.upload_file('test.pdf'))
```

**This is full error log:**

```
======================================================================
ERROR: test_upload_file (apps.reports.test.S3ClientTestCases)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/psymon/Documents/Git/portfolio-manager/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/moto/core/models.py", line 111, in wrapper
    result = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/psymon/Documents/Git/portfolio-manager/apps/reports/test.py", line 54, in test_upload_file
    logger.debug(self.s3_client.upload_file('test.pdf'))
  File "/Users/psymon/Documents/Git/portfolio-manager/apps/reports/services/report_upload_service.py", line 71, in upload_file
    return self.bucket.upload_fileobj(
  File "/Users/psymon/Documents/Git/portfolio-manager/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/boto3/s3/inject.py", line 678, in bucket_upload_fileobj
    return self.meta.client.upload_fileobj(
  File "/Users/psymon/Documents/Git/portfolio-manager/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/boto3/s3/inject.py", line 636, in upload_fileobj
    return future.result()
  File "/Users/psymon/Documents/Git/portfolio-manager/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/s3transfer/futures.py", line 103, in result
    return self._coordinator.result()
  File "/Users/psymon/Documents/Git/portfolio-manager/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/s3transfer/futures.py", line 266, in result
    raise self._exception
  File "/Users/psymon/Documents/Git/portfolio-manager/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/s3transfer/tasks.py", line 139, in __call__
    return self._execute_main(kwargs)
  File "/Users/psymon/Documents/Git/portfolio-manager/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/s3transfer/tasks.py", line 162, in _execute_main
    return_value = self._main(**kwargs)
  File "/Users/psymon/Documents/Git/portfolio-manager/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/s3transfer/upload.py", line 758, in _main
    client.put_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key, Body=body, **extra_args)
  File "/Users/psymon/Documents/Git/portfolio-manager/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 515, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/Users/psymon/Documents/Git/portfolio-manager/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 934, in _make_api_call
    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
botocore.errorfactory.NoSuchBucket: An error occurred (NoSuchBucket) when calling the PutObject operation: The specified bucket does not exist
```

### EDIT #1

*Bucket Policy:*

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Statement1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::some_bucket_name/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

*Granted Permission to User:*

`AmazonS3FullAccess`

I guess something is wrong with AWS account setting but I'm not sure what exactly cause this entire malfunctions...

Please any advice!

Comment: What are the full error messages? Where and how is your script used? How to replicate your problem?

Comment: @Marcin Oh, sorry, I will edit and add those part quickly

Comment: If you don't see a bucket in a successful ListBuckets call, then there is no bucket to upload to.  Also, I'm assuming you're not trying to use "public-reports" as the bucket name, any such name is likely already taken.  Finally, really don't use public-read-write on a bucket unless you understand the inherit dangers of a wide open bucket.

Comment: @AnonCoward, I edited the post, adding the bucket policy and user permission for the access.
Can you see anything wrong from  those? I think that allows I can access to the bucket but as you mentioned I can't access.
Thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solved

The cause of my problem was the annotation on the test code, `@mock_s3`.

Actually, I cannot even call this as problem, but a mistake.

Anyway, if anybody get in trouble with that annotation, I hope my stupid record help you.